# Override tap gesture in tttaributredlabel link

Tags: objective-c, tttattributedlabel

In my application ,  I have a `tttattributedlabel` detect link and open in web view . if I set `uitapgesture`  on this attributed label  then gesture is always fire .
link is not working in any case if tap gesture  set on attributed label .

Comment: Can you show your code please.

Comment: its simple  a string , If string has a link and tap on link open in web view other wise fire a simple gesture ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with it.

```
NSString *pathStr=@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427320/override-tap-gesture-in-tttaributredlabel-link?noredirect=1#comment47025717_29427320";

if ([pathStr hasPrefix:@"http"]) {

    UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    myWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    myWebView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:pathStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
    [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
    myWebView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview: myWebView];
}
```